# to display selected images to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, typescript

[please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNkYL.jpg)I have a grid images page and a button to finish and wanted to select some or all of them and when all or some are selected then the selected image should be display on another page. How I can do this, please help

[see the second image also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfW2H.png)

Comment: add your relevant code please

Answer (score 0):

You have two options actually:

1. You can save the selected images at the server on each selection
2. You can use the local storage of the client to keep the selection of your images.

If you are wondering how to do the second option, please visit this:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

It's very nice explained there

Comment: hello please see the images and help me how i can make it

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer with a link to provide info, how you actually can use the local storage.

Comment: please tell me the first option

Comment: I have a server to save them the user selects the multiple images and then click on "Click to Finish" then the images saved to another page. how can i do this

Comment: did you see the image

Comment: Actually I'd go for the second option if the user can go back to the selection again. Because it's a good practice to make DB calls as less as possible.